# how to send session cookie loaded from a cookielib.MozillaCookieJar compatible file

Tags: python-2.7, cookies, python-requests, cookielib

I have exported cookies from Chrome using cookies.txt Chrome plugin. I can easily replay the request using curl with the cookies exported. Some code like `curl -b mycookie.txt -c mycookie.txt $url` works perfectly.

However, when I was trying to load the session from mycookie.txt using requests, it can't work. After long time debugging, I fond out that requests will not send session cookies(whose expire values is 0 in cookies file) even though I already loaded the expired cookie with following code:

```
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar('mycookie.txt')
cj.load(ignore_discard=True, ignore_expires=True)
print cj  #it shows the session cookie already loaded

s = requests.Session()
s.cookies = cj
r = s.get(url, headers=myheaders, timeout=10, allow_redirects=False)
print r.request.headers   #this clearly shows the request didn't send the session cookie
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me. Let's take a closer look at `requests/models.py`:

```
 def prepare(
    ...
    self.prepare_cookies(cookies) # [1]


 def prepare_cookies(self, cookies):
   ...
    if isinstance(cookies, cookielib.CookieJar):
        self._cookies = cookies
    else:
        ...
    cookie_header = get_cookie_header(self._cookies, self) # [2]
    ...
```

Goto `requests/cookies.py`:

```
 def get_cookie_header(jar, request):
    ...
    jar.add_cookie_header(r) # [3]
    return r.get_new_headers().get("Cookie")
```

Goto `http/cookiejar.py`:

```
def add_cookie_header(self, request):
    ...
    cookies = self._cookies_for_request(request) # [4]
    ...

def _cookies_for_request(self, request):
    """Return a list of cookies to be returned to server."""
    cookies = []
    for domain in self._cookies.keys():
        cookies.extend(self._cookies_for_domain(domain, request)) # [5]
    return cookies

def _cookies_for_domain(self, domain, request):
    cookies = []
    if not self._policy.domain_return_ok(domain, request):
        return []
    _debug("Checking %s for cookies to return", domain)
    cookies_by_path = self._cookies[domain]
    for path in cookies_by_path.keys():
        if not self._policy.path_return_ok(path, request):
            continue
        cookies_by_name = cookies_by_path[path]
        for cookie in cookies_by_name.values():
            if not self._policy.return_ok(cookie, request): # [6] It calls `return_ok()` per cookie line
                _debug("   not returning cookie")
                continue
            cookies.append(cookie)
    return cookies

def return_ok(self, cookie, request):
    ...

    for n in "version", "verifiability", "secure", "expires", "port", "domain":
        fn_name = "return_ok_"+n
        fn = getattr(self, fn_name)
        if not fn(cookie, request): # [7] It will calls `return_ok_domain()`
            return False
    return True

def return_ok_domain(self, cookie, request):
    req_host, erhn = eff_request_host(request) # [8] It calls eff_request_host() to append .local
    domain = cookie.domain

    if domain and not domain.startswith("."):
        dotdomain = "." + domain
    else:
        dotdomain = domain
    ...

    # [10] `.localhost.local` not endwith `.localhost` causes the cookies to be empty later:
    if cookie.version == 0 and not ("."+erhn).endswith(dotdomain):
        _debug("   request-host %s does not match Netscape cookie domain "
               "%s", req_host, domain)
        return False
    return True

IPV4_RE = re.compile(r"\.\d+$", re.ASCII)
def eff_request_host(request):
    """Return a tuple (request-host, effective request-host name).

    As defined by RFC 2965, except both are lowercased.

    """
    erhn = req_host = request_host(request)
    if req_host.find(".") == -1 and not IPV4_RE.search(req_host):
        erhn = req_host + ".local" # [9] Problem here
    return req_host, erhn
```

It means that `localhost` without a dot will be concatenated to `localhost.local`. If, for instance, my cookie file is edited with the `localhost` domain, it will not send the cookie because the domain does not match (`curl` has no such issue):

```
localhost   FALSE   /   FALSE   1712121230  token   xxxxx
```

The cookie will be sent after it appends `.local` (Note that `http`'s localhost only selects lines with the fourth column equal to `FALSE`):

```
localhost.local FALSE   /   FALSE   1712121230  token   xxxxx
```

Alternatively, I can use the same IP, e.g., `s.get(http://127.0.0.1:<port>/...)` and `127.0.0.1 FALSE   /   FALSE   1712121230  token   xxxxx`